# Datagridview column headers assigned colour programatically, but not showing the same colour when the program runs

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview

I have datagridviews that I am creating dynamically which use an array of RGB colours to colour the headers. When I set the row header background colour, it works fine, but when I try to set the column header background colour, it only shows the third colour in the array, even though it is using the correct colour in code and the row header is using the same index.

This is the code used to set the colours

```
grid.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
grid.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Database.colours[colourIndex];
grid.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Database.colours[colourIndex];
Console.WriteLine("Column header colour: " + grid.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor);
Console.WriteLine("Colour array value: " + Database.colours[colourIndex]);
colourIndex++;
```

This is part of the output from the console. It says the BackColor is correct after I assign it, but it is different when I run the program. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fb2NB.png) is what happens. Row headers loop through the colours fine, but column headers are all defaulting to colours[2] (blue).

```
Column header colour: Color [A=255, R=131, G=214, B=129]
Colour array value: Color [A=255, R=131, G=214, B=129]
Column header colour: Color [A=255, R=133, G=215, B=233]
Colour array value: Color [A=255, R=133, G=215, B=233]
Column header colour: Color [A=255, R=99, G=161, B=235]
Colour array value: Color [A=255, R=99, G=161, B=235]
```

This is the array of colours

```
public static readonly Color[] colours = {
            Color.FromArgb(131, 214, 129) // green
            , Color.FromArgb(133, 215, 233) // cyan
            , Color.FromArgb(99, 161, 235)  // blue
            , Color.FromArgb(175, 133, 233) // purple
            , Color.FromArgb(255, 115, 112) // red
            , Color.FromArgb(235, 166, 106) // orange
            , Color.FromArgb(230, 212, 111) // yellow
            };
```

Comment: There seems to be only one `grid.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle` property that applies to all the column headers. Maybe you could create your own `DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell` and override the [DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell.Paint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumnheadercell?view=net-5.0#methods) method. Or just assign each DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell a different `Style`.

Comment: So I looped through each column, did this: `grid.Columns[i].HeaderCell.Style.BackColor = Database.colours[colourIndex];` and it worked. But do you have any idea why the original way works for rows but not columns?

Comment: In your image each row has the same color. And I don't see the context. Where exactly are you calling the code above? Before inserting each row? You seem to set `grid.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor` at the same place in code where you set `grid.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor`. So this is confusing, because you would have to loop through the rows for the first and through the columns for the second.

Comment: I'm using a for loop to create multiple datagridviews. The code is being called within the for loop and I set the column and row count using `grid.ColumnCount` and `grid.RowCount` before the code in question. I do use the two `BackColor` statements at the same place, which sets all row header colours in a grid as intended, but the column statement does not work the same. That is where I am confused.

Comment: These DefaultCellStyles are for **all** the rows and **all** the columns.

Comment: Oh so it's not local to each grid? It'll change the style for all grids in a form?

Comment: It should apply it locally, but remember that these objects are of a reference type. So, if you assigned the same cell style objects (or even the same Column objects) to different grids, they will apply to to different grids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the back color of the header cells like this

```
private void SetHeaderColumnColors(DataGridView dgv)
{
    dgv.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Columns.Count; i++) {
        dgv.Columns[i].HeaderCell.Style.BackColor = colours[i];
    }
}
```

Note that `EnableHeadersVisualStyles` for the grid must be set to `false` to make the custom colors visible.